# Can't generate entity. Symfony 5 + make:entity gives error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have installed Symfony via `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton myapp`.
I am trying to generate entity via `make:entity`. When adding field to entity error occurs.

**Terminal**

```
C:\....\myapp>php bin/console make:entity
 New property name (press <return> to stop adding fields):
 > firstName
In Validator.php line 158:                                                                                                                            
Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Validator::validateDoctrineFieldName() 
must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, 
instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, 
called in C:.....\vendor\symfony\maker-bundle\src\Maker\MakeEntity.php on line 303
```

**My composer.json**

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/asset": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/intl": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/mime": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/notifier": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/process": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/string": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/translation": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.1.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^5.1",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^5.1",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.20",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.1",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.1",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.1",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be related to github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/665 The issue says that you can downgrade the doctrine bundle to 2.1.0 to fix it

Comment: Yes, thanks. Downgrade fix the issue:  "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "2.0.1"