# Incompatibility with maker bundle and Registry - SYMFONY

Tags: php, symfony, plugins, composer-php

I'm new to Symfony and I'm creating a blog for personal use.
But when I try to add fields to an entity using the command *php bin/console make:entity* an error pops out.

> Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Validator::validateDoctrineFieldName() must be an instance of
> Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, call
> ed in C:\Users\user\Documents\CODING\Symfony\calidad\vendor\symfony\maker-bundle\src\Maker\MakeEntity.p
> hp on line 303

I would gladly appreciate all of your help.

It lets me create an entity, but not adding fields.

Here I paste my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.6",
    "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
    "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
    "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^6.0",
    "symfony/debug-bundle": "^4.4",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.20",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "^4.4",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.4",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.4",
    "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^4.4"
},
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582375/cant-generate-entity-symfony-5-makeentity-gives-error

Comment: Although 4.4 will be supported for a couple of more years, since you are starting out fresh I'd recommend getting into 5.1 if that is an option. It does require PHP 7.2, however, but if you can upgrade that I'd strongly recommend it. I can't say if that will fix your problem, unfortunately

Comment: Should be related to github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/665 The issue says that you can downgrade the doctrine bundle to 2.1.0 to fix it

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` v2.1.1 - make sure to have either the former version v2.1.0 or the later one, v2.1.2, installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to incorrect information in the symfony composer configuration file

To solve the problem, re-enter this instruction after installing symfony.

This command solves your problem.
**composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev**