# Symfony skeleton FrameworkExtraBundle not working with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony

I just installed fresh Symfony framework skeleton with annotations and Doctrine and it not works. I have got an error

```
Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter::__construct() 
must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry or null, 
instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, called in
```

my composer file

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.5",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*"
    },
```

Please help.

Comment: What command do you get this error with? Show it to us

Comment: there's probably an error in one of your controllers (ParamConverter is used to provide controller arguments)

Comment: Possible a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582492/incompatibility-with-maker-bundle-and-registry-symfony  Try a composer update to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same problem today after installing the new symfony binary, **composer update** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have added to the config/packages/sensio_framework_extra.yaml
this lines and it working

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    router:
        annotations: false
    request:
        converters: true
        disable: ['doctrine.orm']
```